# How to ask some one about their view about a place

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I am trying to ask someone about the place they visit. 
The way I used to ask him is

> How he found the Paris?

Is this the right way to ask someone about their view about that place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'How's Paris?'

'How did you find Paris?'

There are many variations. 'How's Paris?' is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Verbally, I would use phrases like:

What did you think of Paris?

How did you like Paris?

Is Paris a nice place?

How was Paris?